# Links inside a fancybox popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I have an issue that I am lost on how to solve. In my program, when a user clicks an image the fancybox script runs causing a new image to appear as a popup. However, in that image I would like to be able to place links as well. Basically I want to use link blocks of specific width and height and position within the popup image, creating a link within a link. Is that even possible to do?

Here is some code:

```
<!--Using the fancybox functions -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#contentArea a").fancybox({
                'overlayShow'   : false,
                'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
                'transitionOut' : 'elastic'

            });
            });
    </script>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="contentArea" role="main">
             <a href="../images/IRPA_two-navigation-books.png" title="Raj Sharma" style="width: 217px;height: 117px;position: absolute;display: block;top: 340px;left: 450px; background-image:url(../images/transparent.png)"></a>         
</div>
```

As you can see I created a fancybox image popup for a block link in a specific position. How do I create links with specified width/height and position within the popup fancy box image?

This is the tool/library that I am using, in-case anyone is confused:
http://fancybox.net/

Thanks!

Comment: Does the image in the popup, when clicked, close the popup?

Comment: yeah it should. It should take you to a different page.

Comment: Also note that its not an image that will be clicked in the popup. I would like to have transparent block links of specified width and height that I can position at locations on the popup image to be clicked by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily:

```
var html = "<!--- some html here to add to the fancybox -->";
$('#fancybox-title-over').html(html);
$('#fancybox-title-over').css('background-color' , 'transparent');
```

It will appear in the overlay title as seen in the sixth example on http://fancybox.net/

Comment: So the variable html will hold the link styled with a certain position, width and height and then $('#fancybox-title-over').html(html); simply applies it to the fancybox?

sounds great! Thanks!

Comment: @user1410668 Hold on a second, which example is closest to yours?

Comment: I would say the 6th or 7th one. They have text appearing on the image, but I need a link displayed as block and is invisible. Basically I want a positioned link instead of the text that they have and I would prefer that I can style the link to have a transparent background as well.

The issue isn't as simple as adding text.

Comment: @user1410668 - I edited the answer to fit your need.  Make sure you configure the fancybox popups to use the over title. i.e. set `titlePosition` to `'over'`.